# ion tabs : after tapping menu tabs, icons will duplicate

Tags: tabs, ionic-framework

here's the screenshoot of my tabs menu problem.[click here to view screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQu9M.png)

here is my code :

```
<ion-view>
     <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
        <ion-tab title="Clock In" icon="icon-clock-in" ng-click="mn.clockInLog()">
            <ion-nav-view name="clockIn"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Attendance" icon="icon-attendance" ng-click="mn.backLog()">
            <ion-nav-view name="attendance"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Leave" icon="icon-leave" ui-sref="main.leave">
            <ion-nav-view name="leave"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Overtime" icon="icon-overtime" ui-sref="main.overtime">
            <ion-nav-view name="overtime"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="More" icon="icon-more" ui-sref="main.more">
            <ion-nav-view name="more"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working.

Noticed that the duplicated icons where those where I used `ui-sref=` as in:

```
<ion-tab icon="ion-android-restaurant" title="Menu" ui-sref="logged_in.menus">
```

Changed `ui-sref` to `ng-click=` and now it works: no duplicated icons. Why? I don't know... but as a workaround this *kills the bug*.

So, change the html to:

```
<ion-tab icon="ion-android-restaurant" title="Menu" ng-click="menus()">
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.menus = function () {
    $state.go('logged_in.menus');
};
```